# Laravel Storageに保存されている動画をheader、またはstream関数で再生したいです。

Tags: php, laravel, stream

どうしても解決ができておらず、ご存知の方々にお聞きしたいと思います。

結論から申し上げますと、Azure Storage上にある動画ファイルを再生したいです。
しかし、Local環境と開発環境と動きが異なり、iPhoneの再生ができません。

**やってみたこと１**

```
    $path = Storage::disk('local')->path("common/".$fileName);
    $file_size = filesize($path);
    $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
    $status_code = 200;
    $headers = [
        'Content-type' => 'video/mp4',
        'Accept-Ranges' => 'bytes',
        'Content-Length' => $file_size
    ];

    $range = $request->header('Range');

    if(!is_null($range)) {
        if(preg_match('|bytes=([0-9]+)\-|', $range, $matches)) {
            $start = intval($matches[1]);
            if(fseek($fp, $start) === 0) {
                $status_code = 206;
                $headers['Content-Length'] = $file_size - $start;
                $headers['Content-Range'] = sprintf(
                    'bytes %d-%d/%d',
                    $start,
                    ($file_size-1),
                    $file_size
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return response()->stream(function() use($fp) {
        fpassthru($fp);
    }, $status_code, $headers);
```

Storageを'azure'に変更して、サーバー上に行くと、pathが **storage/app 以降から**始まりまして、fopenが効かなかったです。
FullPathを返したらできるかと思い、試してみましたが、うまくできませんでした。

> Localでpathを実行したら
> C:\Users\・・・\storage\app\common\filename.mp4
>
> サーバーでpathを実行したら
> common\filename.mp4

**やっていみたこと２**

```
$file_size = Storage::disk('azure')->size("common/".$fileName);
$content = Storage::disk('azure')->get("common/".$fileName);
return response($content)->header('Content-Type', 'video/mp4', 'Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
```

PCクロームでは再生ができましたが、PC Internet Explorer、iPhone Safariでは再生ができませんでした。

現在のコード

```
$url = Storage::disk('azure')->url("common/".$fileName);
$path = storage_path(Storage::disk('azure')->path("common/".$fileName));

    if (file_exists($url)) {
        $file_size = filesize($url);
        $fp = fopen($url, 'rb');
    } elseif (file_exists($path)) {
        $file_size = filesize($path);
        $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
    } else {
        // この方式はiPhoneでは開かない
        $file_size = Storage::disk('azure')->size("common/".$fileName);
        $content = Storage::disk('azure')->get("common/".$fileName);
        return response($content)->header('Content-Type', 'video/mp4', 'Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
    }

    $status_code = 200;
    $headers = [
        'Content-type' => 'video/mp4',
        'Accept-Ranges' => 'bytes',
        'Content-Length' => $file_size
    ];
    $range = $request->header('Range');

    if(!is_null($range)) {
        if(preg_match('|bytes=([0-9]+)\-|', $range, $matches)) {
            $start = intval($matches[1]);
            if(fseek($fp, $start) === 0) {
                $status_code = 206;
                $headers['Content-Length'] = $file_size - $start;
                $headers['Content-Range'] = sprintf(
                    'bytes %d-%d/%d',
                    $start,
                    ($file_size-1),
                    $file_size
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return response()->stream(function() use($fp) {
        fpassthru($fp);
    }, $status_code, $headers);
```

どう修正すれば iPhone でも再生ができますでしょうか。
ご存知の方、教えて頂けますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: Webアプリケーションの問題なのか動画自体の問題なのか切り分けるために、アプリケーション経由ではなく直接ブラウザに表示するとみることは可能ですか？生の動画をどこかにおいてそれらのそれぞれブラウザで表示してみると問題なく表示されますか？

Comment: @keitaro_so 　コメントありがとうございます。生の表示はうまくできます。Storageではなく、Public上に乗せてVideoタグを使うと、問題なく再生できました。ただし、事情があり、PublicではなくStorageを使ってheaderで返さないとなりません。。。

Comment: 生の動画とアプリでHeaderやコンテンツを流した時にheaderなどに違いはないですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so 

コメントありがとうございます。
headerですが、生の場合、Content-Length: 17811861 が設定され、
Storageからは、Content-Lengthがありませんでした。

しかしながら、Content-LengthがあったときもiPhoneでの再生はできませんでした。。。

よろしくお願いいたします。